# Getting many welcome messages from the same user

Tags: actions-on-google

I am getting many welcome messages from the same user, is it some kind of a monitoring system by Google? 
How can I learn to ignore those requests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google periodically issues a [health check](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/actions-health-check) against your Action, usually about every 5-10 minutes. Your Action should respond to it normally so Google knows if there is something wrong. If there is, you will receive email that your Action is unavailable because it is unhealthy. They will continue to monitor it and, when healthy again, will restore it.

You don't need to ignore those requests, however you may wish to, either to save on resources or to avoid logging it all the time.

With a library such as [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/), it detects it and responds automatically - there is nothing you need to to. For other libraries, you will need to examine the raw input sent in the body of your webhook request.

If you are using the Action SDK, you should examine the `inputs` array to see if there is one with an argument named "is_health_check". If you are using Dialogflow, then you would need to look under `originalDetectIntentRequest.data.inputs`.